# How to fix "required" attribute when using express-handlebars?

Tags: express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am currently using express-handlebars and have created a home.hbs (home.handlebars) file in which everything works as expected except for one thing. The "required" attribute. Not only does it not work but it is not even highlighted as a keyword in my .hbs file (I'm using vscode if it matters). I have tried all the suggestions in the following article https://fellowtuts.com/html-css/html5-required-attribute-validation-not-working/. However none of these suggestions corrected my issue. Thank you in advance for anyone who helps.

Comment: can you share the code that's failing?
also, express and node versions?
finally, could you check the console to see if there's any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that handlebars ignores attributes like `required` that accept a `Boolean` which their values are not specified.
so you should specify its value like `required="true"`